# Dynamically change JavaScript prototypes cause problems

Tags: javascript

[image]

I am just curious about the behavior of dynamically changing constructor's prototype in JavaScript. And I got the above result.

It seems like your already constructed instance will not share the "new" prototype's properties.

I was wondering if it's simply just the choice of such design? Because I expected to see the instance share the "new" prototype's properties. Thanks!

Comment: _Mutating_ the prototype object shared by the constructor and the instances will propagate to both. _Replacing_ the prototype object  of the constructor with another object will not update already created instances.

Comment: Thanks! It's clear now. That's just how it works :)

Answer (score 4):

When an object is constructed, its prototype reference is set at that point according to the value of the constructor function's `prototype` property. If the constructor property later changes value, the already-constructed objects are not affected.

That's just how it works.

So, yes, that can cause problems. I guess you could exploit it for some purpose, but that'd be pretty strange.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Yea, I would just take that. Though it's a little bit surprised for me since dynamically adding methods to prototypes will affect the instances. But apparently it's not working if we change the prototypes.

Comment: check `test.__proto__` and you will see that object is the prototype _before_ the swap. The `__proto__` property is the (sort of unnoficial) place that an instance stores a reference to it prototype.

Comment: `__proto__` is giving me the current prototype. But `.prototype` is referring to the previous prototype before the swap..

Comment: Really? http://jsfiddle.net/fgzvzk89/ I get `Object {a:1}` logged twice. (for the record I was agreeing with you, just explaining why)

Comment: @Matsu the prototype reference from **instances** is available in the (non-standard and deprecated) "\_\_proto\_\_" property. It won't change when the constructor prototype changes, as the fiddle posted in the Alex Wayne's comment shows.

Comment: Hi! Could you look at this http://jsfiddle.net/8d89ecdw/ I do got `function Super() {}` logged twice. But they are the newest prototypes. It should log `Super {}` twice I think..

Comment: @Matsu you're logging the \_\_proto\_\_ property of the **same object**. Your test does not make any sense.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, but please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/fgzvzk89/   Alex is logging on the same object twice as well but he is getting what he wants. I am a bit confused.

Comment: ON the third line you do `Sub.prototype = Super;` which sets the prototype to a _function_. So `function Super() {}` is initial prototype object that is preserved. After you do `Sub.prototype = new Super;` you'd expect to get `Super {}` instead, an instance and not a function at all. At this point, this example is a bit too contrived to be useful.